# Get data out of string

Tags: php, regex, string, string-search

I am going to parse a log file and I wonder how I can convert such a string:

`[5189192e][game]: kill killer='0:Tee' victim='1:nameless tee' weapon=5 special=0`

into some kind of array:

```
$log['5189192e']['game']['killer'] = '0:Tee';
$log['5189192e']['game']['victim'] = '1:nameless tee';
$log['5189192e']['game']['weapon'] = '5';
$log['5189192e']['game']['special'] = '0';
```

Comment: You could use `$arr = explode(' ', $str);` to split `$str` by space. Then you could do the same on `=` to get your key->value pairs.

Comment: sscanf() might be an option - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php if the log file entries always follow this basic structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the function **[preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)** and a **[regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)** you will be able to generate an array, which you then just have to organize into your multi-dimensional array:

here's the code:

```
$log_string = "[5189192e][game]: kill killer='0:Tee' victim='1:nameless tee' weapon=5 special=0";
preg_match_all("/^\[([0-9a-z]*)\]\[([a-z]*)\]: kill (.*)='(.*)' (.*)='(.*)' (.*)=([0-9]*) (.*)=([0-9]*)$/", $log_string, $result);

$log[$result[1][0]][$result[2][0]][$result[3][0]] = $result[4][0];
$log[$result[1][0]][$result[2][0]][$result[5][0]] = $result[6][0];
$log[$result[1][0]][$result[2][0]][$result[7][0]] = $result[8][0];
$log[$result[1][0]][$result[2][0]][$result[9][0]] = $result[10][0];
// $log is your formatted array
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use function [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all) and **regular expressions**.

For example to get **5189192e** you need to use expression

```
/[0-9]{7}e/
```

This says that the first 7 characters are digits last character is **e** you can change it to fits any letter

```
/[0-9]{7}[a-z]+/
```

it is almost the same but fits every letter in the end

more advanced example with subpatterns and whole details

```
<?php
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all('\[[0-9]{7}e\]\[game]: kill killer=\'([0-9]+):([a-zA-z]+)\' victim=\'([0-9]+):([a-zA-Z ]+)\' weapon=([0-9]+) special=([0-9])+\', $str, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
?>
```

- **$str** is string to be parsed
- **$matches** contains the whole data you needed to be pared like killer id, weapon, name etc.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' on line 2

However, I am totally satisfied with sebataz answer. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: because there is one '' that need to be escaped :) regex was okay :) I've checked it with online regex :)

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need a regex. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is the pertaining PHP function and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.introduction.php) is a regex syntax reference.